Semi-Automatic Classification plugin error - QGIS - failed dependencies
I had been using SCP for the last year and just recently it stopped working. If I run any process that generates new images, those images are empty (all no data). I tested the dependencies and got:
-GDAL: Success
-GDAL subprocess: Success
-SNAP subprocess: Fail
-Python multiprocess: Fail
-GDAL multiprocess: Fail
-NumPy: Success
-SciPy: Success
-Matplotlib: Success
-Internet connection: Success
Running QGIS 3.16.16 in Ubuntu 18.04 with Python 3.7. I tried uninstalling SCP and installing again but now the SCP dock doesn't even apper in QGIS and no SCP menu is found. How can I fix this?
